# Apache poi How to changes Image width?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx, birt

I am trying to create Birt XLSX Emitter, everything is working find expect Images, Images are not to taking width/height accordingly.

Note: Poi version is: 3.9.0

Here is the few sample images:

[image]

Here we can see in A3 image is not taking proper height and in A4 not taking proper width and height also.

And expected result is :

[image]

Please find below sample code, not sure how to calculate accurately:

```
private void imageData( int type, byte[] data,
         int column, int colSpan, int rowSpan,
        int styleId,ImageData image )
{
    IImageContent imagecontent = image.getImageContent();
    this.cell  = this.row.getCell(column -1);
    
    if (this.cell == null) {
        this.cell = this.row.createCell(column -1);
    }
    this.cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
    String mimeType = imagecontent.getMIMEType();

    if( data != null ) {

            int imageIdx = wb.addPicture( data, imageType );
            
            Drawing drawing = null;

            drawing = this.sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

            float ptHeight = cell.getRow().getHeightInPoints();
            if( imagecontent.getHeight() != null ) {
                ptHeight = 116; ///fontSizeInPoints( imagecontent.getHeight().toString() );
            }
            
            int endCol = this.cell.getColumnIndex() + colSpan;
            double lastColWidth = widthUnits2Millimetres( (short)this.sheet.getColumnWidth( endCol ) )
                    + 2.0;
            int dx = anchorDxFromMM( lastColWidth, lastColWidth );
            
            if (colSpan == 0) {
                this.sheet.setColumnWidth(this.cell.getColumnIndex(), poiColumnWidthFromDimension(imagecontent.getWidth()));
                setSize(cell.getColumnIndex(), poiColumnWidthFromDimension(imagecontent.getWidth()));
            }
           
            double mmWidth = 0.0;
            if(isAbsolute(imagecontent.getWidth())) {
                mmWidth = imagecontent.getWidth().convertTo(DimensionType.UNITS_MM);
            } else if(isPixels(imagecontent.getWidth())) {
                mmWidth = pixels2Millimetres( imagecontent.getWidth().getMeasure() );
            }
            
                float widthRatio = (float)(mmWidth / lastColWidth);
                ptHeight = ptHeight / widthRatio;

            int rowsSpanned = rowSpan;
            float neededRowHeightPoints = ptHeight;
            
            for( int i = 0; i < rowsSpanned; ++i ) {
                int rowIndex = this.cell.getRowIndex() + i;
                if (this.sheet.getRow(rowIndex) != null) {
                    neededRowHeightPoints -= this.sheet.getRow(rowIndex).getHeightInPoints();
                }
                
            }
        
            if( neededRowHeightPoints > this.cell.getRow().getHeightInPoints()) {
                this.cell.getRow().setHeightInPoints( neededRowHeightPoints );
            }


            ClientAnchor anchor = this.wb.getCreationHelper().createClientAnchor();
            anchor.setCol1(this.cell.getColumnIndex());
            anchor.setRow1(this.cell.getRowIndex());
            anchor.setCol2(endCol);
            anchor.setRow2(this.cell.getRowIndex());
            anchor.setDx2(dx);
            anchor.setDy2( anchorDyFromPoints( ptHeight, this.cell.getRow().getHeightInPoints() ) );
            
            anchor.setDx1(2 * XSSFShape.EMU_PER_PIXEL);
            anchor.setDy1(2 * XSSFShape.EMU_PER_PIXEL);
            
            anchor.setAnchorType(ClientAnchor.MOVE_DONT_RESIZE);
            
            
            Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, imageIdx);

    }

    
}
public int anchorDyFromPoints( float height, float rowHeight ) {
    return (int)( height * XSSFShape.EMU_PER_POINT );
}
public int anchorDxFromMM( double widthMM, double colWidthMM ) {
    return (int)(widthMM * 36000); 
}
```

Comment: First you would need increasing the height of row 4 (`Row.setHeight...`). And what about simply setting row 2 of the anchor to the next row (`anchor.setRow2(this.cell.getRowIndex()+1);`)? Then the whole calculation of `Dy` is not necessary because `Dy` can be 0 then.

Comment: So I have to find the row height using the height of the image, right!

Comment: There is `Row.setHeightInPoints`. And there is [org.apache.poi.util.Units](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/util/Units.html) to calculate from pixels to points and vice versa. So if you have the wanted height in points or pixels ...